# Creating Secondary Calendars In a GSuite Domain

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

- I have created a GSuite account with a domain called redu.club
- I created a project and a service account using GSuite admin email
- Added that service account to the admin calendar using share settings and have given full manage rights.

I am trying to create secondary calendars under the redu-admin@redu.club account. Here is the code I have:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/redu-service-account.json');

define('SCOPES', Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

function createCalendar()
{
    try {
        // Create and configure a new client object.        
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Redu');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([SCOPES]);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

        // Calendar creation
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();

        $calendar->setSummary('test');
        $calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

        $createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar);

        // Make the newly created calendar public
        $rule = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRule();
        $scope = new Google_Service_Calendar_AclRuleScope();

        $scope->setType("default");
        $scope->setValue("");
        $rule->setScope($scope);
        $rule->setRole("reader");

        $createdRule = $service->acl->insert($createdCalendar->getId(), $rule);

        return $createdCalendar->getId();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This code creates a calendar but when I go to the calendar of redu-admin@redu.club, I can't see it. My guess is it's creating a calendar under the service account. When I try adding the line
`$this->client->setSubject('redu-admin@redu.club');`, the error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to create a secondary calendar for a user, you need to impersonate this user

You already tried it correctly:

```
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Redu');
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope([SCOPES]);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setSubject('redu-admin@redu.club');
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

But there two important steps that need to be followed previously:

1. Enable domain-wide delegation for the service account [in the GCP console](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#create_the_service_account_and_credentials)
2. Provide the service account the necessary delegation scopes in the [Admin console](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)